# When (exactly) can equality be proposed between different types using '='?

Tags: idris

In the documentation, it says:

> Equality in Idris is heterogeneous, meaning that we can even propose
>   equalities between values in different types:
>
> ```
> idris_not_php : 2 = "2"
> ```

That particular example compiles, but the hole is presented as being of type `fromInteger 2 = "2"`. Given that `fromInteger 2` can belong to any type that is an instance of `Num`, maybe the compiler isn't quite clever enough to deduce that the value of `2` is not a `String`?

In comparison, the following slightly different code fails to compile:

```
idris_not_php : S (S Z) = "2"
```

The compiler reports a type mismatch between `Nat` and `String`.

Also, the following does compile successfully:

```
Num String where
  (+) x y = y
  (*) x y = y
  fromInteger n = "2"

idris_not_php : 2 = "2"
idris_not_php = the (the String 2 = "2") Refl
```

And these two compile:

```
idris_not_php : S (S Z) ~=~ "2"
idris_not_php = ?hole

two_is_two : 2 ~=~ 2
two_is_two = Refl
```

Is there any particular rule about when `=` can be used between things that are of different types, or is it just a matter of using `~=~` when `=` doesn't work? Are `~=~` and `=` semantically identical, and if so, why is `~=~` even necessary?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992369/2900502) have some theoretical notes about heterogeneous equality in Idris. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226950/using-heterogenous-equality-with) has example of why you may need `(~=~)`.

I just want to add a little about `idris_not_php : 2 = "2"` example. This **can** be type checked if you have `Num` instance for `String` type just as you did. Integral constants in `Idris` are polymorphic. Though, any reasonable program wouldn't have such instance for `String` because it doesn't make sense.